# How to reshape a pandas dataframe specific format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code in python which is a simple Dataframe that produces the result in the image on the left side, and I would like to reshape the Dataframe so that it produces the output that is in the right side

Is there a way to do it without looping multiple times through the Dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol':['AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','BYND','BYND','BYND']
    ,'quarter':['2019Q1', '2019Q2', '2019Q3', '2019Q4', '2020Q1', '2019Q3', '2019Q4', '2020Q1']
    , 'change_pct':[.5, .3, .1, .4, 0, .8, .2, .3]})
```

Dataframe desired output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use `pivot` for this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol':['AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','BYND','BYND','BYND']
    ,'quarter':['2019Q1', '2019Q2', '2019Q3', '2019Q4', '2020Q1', '2019Q3', '2019Q4', '2020Q1']
    , 'change_pct':[.5, .3, .1, .4, 0, .8, .2, .3]})
df = df.pivot(index = 'symbol',columns='quarter',values='change_pct').fillna('')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
quarter 2019Q1 2019Q2  2019Q3  2019Q4  2020Q1
symbol                                       
AAPL       0.5    0.3     0.1     0.4     0.0
BYND                      0.8     0.2     0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [pd.Dataframe.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) - something like

```
pivoted = df.pivot(index=symbol, columns=quarter, values=change_pct)
```